# How to use 'grep' with characters like * and _?

Tags: command-line, grep

I need to find some text in one or more files.

This is what I use:

```
grep -irI "hello" ~/
```

However, if I want to find a string containing characters like `*` or `_` then these seem to be ignored.

Let's say I want to search in all files for the string `a**__`.

How can I do that? Many thanks - I just can't figure this out!

Answer (score 2):

There is a -F option:

```
-F, --fixed-strings
Interpret PATTERN as a list of fixed strings, separated by newlines, any of which is to be matched.  (-F is specified by POSIX.)
```

This will disable searching by regular expressions and interpreting characters like `*` or `.`. Example:

```
$ cat test 
a**__
$ grep -F 'a**__' test 
a**__
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use an escape character (`\`)  in front of `*` because, otherwise, your string to search will became a regular expression.

For example, if you want to search for `**__`, you can use:

```
 grep -irI "\*\*__" ~/
```

More about: [In a regular expression, which characters need escaping?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/20804/in-a-regular-expression-which-characters-need-escaping).

Answer (score 0):

A simple double quote (" ") with an escape character ( '\' )will do the job.

for example if I want to search for ind*x.html from the current folder I will use :

```
grep -r "ind\*x.html" ./
```

Note : If you are not using without quotes then you need to use two backslash.

```
grep -r ind\\*x.html ./
```

Both will search for ind*x.html term in the files.

Comment: Although two will usually work, you strictly need *three* backslashes, one to escape the `*` for `grep`, and another *two* to fully escape the `\*` for the shell.