# Mysterious > prompt from missing right apostrophe

Tags: bash

If I type for example

```
grep 'needle
>
```

I get sent to a mysterious `>` prompt from which <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>C</kbd> (or restarting the terminal) is seemingly the only escape.

1. What is this prompt?
2. Why doesn't it terminate when I enter <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Z</kbd>?
3. Why isn't it better designed to detect trapped newbies?  Sure, maybe in some ridiculously contrived edge case there would be a reason to open this `>` prompt and then input something like `"quit\nexit\nhelp\nCTRL-Z\nlogout\n"`, but if the user starts entering those things, Ubuntu should at least issue a helpful response message (e.g., "Are you trying to get out of this prompt?  If so use <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>C</kbd>.  If not, ignore this message.") that wouldn't interfere with whatever weird purpose the prompt serves.

Answer (score 2):

This is because you opened a quote (`"` or `'`) so the shell assumes that the command in continuing, what is indicated by this `>` character. So until the closing quote you will get the `>` prompt to finish the started command.

This is when you want to echo something with newline in it, for example:

```
user@host:~$ echo "this
> is a text
> with multiple
> newlines"
```

outputs:

```
this
is a text
with multiple
newlines
```

To abort you can also hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd>.

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing mysterious. That prompt (`>`) is suggesting you that the shell is waiting for second quote `'` and a filename to finish your command. If you want to search for `'needle` then use:

```
grep \'needle filename
```

And <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> is used for suspending a job, but you don't have any job started only  by entering `grep 'needle`.

And, at the third point, I would say that this will sound ridiculous for users who really work with the terminal. Plus: how do you thing that the terminal could detect if someone is newbie or not? And what if someone really wants to enter those strings: "quit, exit, help, logout"?

See also:

- [How to use 'grep' with characters like * and _?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/363821/how-to-use-grep-with-characters-like-and)
- [What's different between Ctrl+Z and Ctrl+C in Unix command line?](https://superuser.com/questions/262942/whats-different-between-ctrlz-and-ctrlc-in-unix-command-line)

Comment: Ah I suspected as much but When I do

    $grep 'needle
    >'

I am tranferred to another mysterious prompt with NO > or $ or anything.  This is of course because that's where

    grep 'needle'

would send me, and what I really need to do is

    grep 'needle' *

(why is grep so badly designed in that sense?  but that's another issue for another post)

Comment: When you type `grep 'needle >'` the command grep waits for input from stdin. So everything you type. When you type `needle >` then, it will be grepped and printed... Can be very strange to shell beginners =)

Comment: @Anonymous See also `man grep`. This time, when you use `grep 'needle >'` type ` blabla needle > blabla` to see what's happening. And this time yes, you have a job that can be stopped, so you can use Ctrl+Z. See also my new edits at the answer.

Comment: Thanks for all the illuminating help.  So as a side topic, why does the > prompt ignore CTRL-Z?  I'm having trouble picturing any reason why it apparently intercepts the signal and ignores it.  Why else would the user be pressing CTRL-Z if not to kill whatever is going on (the > prompt)?

Comment: @Anonymous Have you looked over: [What's different between Ctrl+Z and Ctrl+C in Unix command line?](http://superuser.com/questions/262942/whats-different-between-ctrlz-and-ctrlc-in-unix-command-line). Is not clear yet for you that Ctrl+Z doesn't kill anything? It only **suspend a process for later resumption**. Only Ctrl+C can kill whatever you are doing in terminal.

Comment: @RaduRădeanu: (1) “… the shell is waiting for second quote `'` and a filename to finish your command.” No, the shell is waiting for you to type a complete command (by closing off all quoted strings and typing an unescaped newline) or a syntax error. The shell doesn’t know what `grep`’s syntax is, and, in fact, will accept `grep 'pattern'` to start a `grep` process that reads from the standard input – which is the terminal in this case – although the shell doesn’t know what `grep` is going to do with that solitary argument.

Comment: @RaduRădeanu: (2) Referring a professed newbie to `man grep` won’t help him to understand what I just explained – that if `grep` is invoked with one argument and no redirection, it will start reading data from the terminal. (3) Regarding the last two comments: the shell probably could catch Ctrl+Z while it’s reading what it thinks is a multi-line command and abort it; the authors just chose not to. (Perhaps because they didn’t want to encourage newbies to use Ctrl+Z when they don’t understand it.)

Answer (score 0):

The prompt is just the standard input. the ' character is interpreted as 'start of a string' so it excepts for a closing '. when you press return before the closing ' it is interpreted as a newline. you can continue writing what you want. when you type a ' and press enter it gets the whole string you wrote